# GCP Https Load Balancer SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, load-balancing, https, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a Https load balancer using yaml and Jinja files on GCP deployment manager. But I am not sure how to provide SSL certificate. In the "sslCertificates" of "compute.v1.targetHttpsProxy", it expects the value to be URL to sslCertificates. How do i create an URL for the SSL certificate. Earlier, I was trying to provide the certificate itself in the field but I get an error saying "The URL is malformed".

Please help if anyone knows how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The SSL certificate is a separate resource that you can create through the GCP console, gcloud sdk, API or deployment manager template.

1. If you already have the SSL certificate created - find the name of the SSL certificate using `gcloud compute ssl-certificates list` and get its URL with `gcloud compute ssl-certificates describe CERT-NAME`. The URL will look like - `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/sslCertificates/SSL-CERT-NAME`

Once you get the SSL URL, add the `sslCertificates` key in your yaml or jinja file with the value of the URL to the certificate for your TargetHttpsProxy. **Make sure the SSL certificate URL is a list or an array.** as shown below in the body of TargetHttpsProxy resource - [SSL certificate resource representation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/targetHttpsProxies).

`{
  "id": string,
  "creationTimestamp": string,
  "name": string,
  "description": string,
  "selfLink": string,
  "urlMap": string,
  "sslCertificates": [
    string
  ],
  "quicOverride": enum,
  "sslPolicy": string,
  "kind": string
}`

2. SSL certificate doesn't exist - then create first and do step(1). You can find the SSL certificate resource representation in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates/insert). Some other info on GCP SSL certificates [is here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates).